# Webdriver stale element exception when element DOM didn't change

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using WebDriver in Java.

I want to get all the amount values from the amount field below, so what I am planning to do it to loop throug each table row, and find if the check box is selected, set the amount to a number defined.

[image]

Example source code can be found here at:
http://eric-lin.net/upload/index.php

I use the following Java method to find the amount field value:

```
public void fillInAllAmountForSelectedItems() {

    List<WebElement> allItems = driver
            .findElements(By
                    .xpath("//table[@id = 'bulkPaymentForm:itemTable']//tbody[@id = 'bulkPaymentForm:itemTable:tbody_element']//tr[contains(@class, 'handCursor row-border tranItemRow')]"));
    System.out.println(allItems.size());
    //return 3, expected

    waitTimer(2, 1000);

    for (WebElement item : allItems) {
        System.out.println(item.findElement(By.xpath("//td[4]"))
                .getAttribute("Value"));
    }       
}
```

Most of the time, the foreach loop will fail because of stale element exception. Which I don't understand because the DOM didn't change.

When it works, the foreach loop does not print anything so it looks like it doesn't locate the element correct.

How can I do to fix it, and what do I need to do to fulfill the purpose of this function to fill in amount value for all the checked items?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Did you tried adding `wait()` function? try to execute in step by step (debug mode) if you are using eclipse

Comment: Note  that the `input` field within the `td` will contain the amount, not the `td` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling `StaleElementException` is usually a try retry till you succeed story. The DOM might refresh for several reasons causing the element to go stale.

A strategy sometimes used and often effective when working with list of elements is to obtain each item one by one. An excellent solution is posted [here](https://coderwall.com/p/koim7w), sample code is as below.

You will need to construct the xpath /css selector to refer to the required table cell accordingly. Note that the value is to be retrieved from the amount `input` field from within the `td` - If you try to get the text from `td` it will be blank, like you see now.

```
//get the number of items that are required
int size = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table#mytable>tbody>tr>td[4]/input")).size();

//now work with each one individually, rather than with a list
for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    String locator = String.format("table#mytable>tbody>tr[%d]>td[4]/input", i);
    WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(locator));
    //get or set the value of the input element
    System.out.println(inputField.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Faiz, your solution looks great but I can't seem to locate the amount field elements by the cssSelector. I replaced the id `#mytable` with the id of the payment table `#bulkPaymentForm:itemTable` and it is complaining about `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An invalid or illegal string was specified`.

Comment: I use xpath `//table[@id = 'bulkPaymentForm:itemTable']//tbody//tr[%d]/td[4]/input"` and it works, but I still want to know why the cssSelector doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: The `:` in your table id might be the culprit for the cssSelector to not work. The `:` has a specific meaning for css and is used to specify pseudo classes. See section 6.6 pseudo classes [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Comment: Using the xpath, were you able to access the fields and get rid of the `StaleElementException` ?

Comment: I was able to retrieve the fields and get rid of the `StaleElementException` using xpath. Your solution overall is very good for me, thank you so much.